Semantic version and loading from CDN
I am loading some things from CDN, like
// https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/using-workbox-window
const urlWorkboxWindow = "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.2.0/workbox-window.prod.mjs";

Today the latest version is "6.2.0". That will of course probably change.
I write my code to be compatible version "6". I would like to always load the latest version of "6". Is that possible somehow? I mean, is there some convention for this?
